# Hide Recurrence in Edit Mode of SharePoint Calencar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, content-editor-web-part

I'm using the following code to hide the recurrence and all day event fields in a SharePoint Event Calendar.  It works for the initial event.  But if a user goes in to edit the event, the recurring fields are still showing.  How can I remove those from the Edit part of the calendar as well?

```
$('nobr:contains("All Day Event")').closest('tr').hide();
 $('nobr:contains("Recurrence")').closest('tr').hide();
```

Comment: Hi, You need to add same code in Edit form of Calendar

Comment: That's what I'm asking.  I don't see a way to do that or a place to add the code.

Comment: Wait a second.  I think I have it now in the Default Edit form.  Thx!